# Can QML replace OpenGL in Qt?

Tags: qt, opengl, qml

QML as per my knowledge does the same thing as OpenGL, right? So can I completely replace OpenGLwith QML ?

Whats the basic difference between QML and OpenGL?

When does people prefer QML over OpenGL and vice versa?

Comment: Your knowledge is incorrect, qml and OpenGL are two completely different things, the first is a declarative language the second is a graphics api.

Comment: @ddriver: you should make that comment an answer

Comment: Perhaps you mean Qt Quick, since QML is a declarative language that is completely detached from any graphics and can be used for, e.g., [build systems](http://doc.qt.io/qbs/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your knowledge is incorrect, QML and OpenGL are two completely different things, the first is a declarative language the second is a graphics API.

QtQuick which uses QML usually uses OpenGL for its graphics, but that's a back-end you don't have any access to (it actually got a little more accessible in the recent releases but I expect not many people will go into tweaking that, and even if they did, it would be in C++, not QML).

There is [Qt3D](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-index.html), which has a QML API, but it is just some basic stuff and it is high level - by no means a substitute to OpenGL which is very low level. That means it will be much easier to put some 3D models, cameras, materials and such with Qt3D, things you'd normally not do in OpenGL directly, but with an API built on top of OpenGL.

Comment: +1, about "backend you don't have any access to": one can combine QQ with custom opengl shades though, tweak the opengl settings or integrate it with other custom opengl code. So it's not just a hidden implementation detail.